# What's the fastest way of creating dictionary inside list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_text1 = 'text1'
my_text2 = 'text2'
my_list = []
my_dict = {}
my_dict['Key1'] = my_text1
my_dict['Key2'] = my_text2
my_list.append(my_dict)
```

What's the fastest way to create a list of dictionaries? 
Is it possible to use write variable in dictionary?

I wanted to make something like this:

```
my_list.append('key1'= %s, 'key2'= %s % (my_text1, my_text2))
```

I know it's wrong syntax but It's my goal to append different values from variables

Comment: But what's the point on doing "the fastest" ? do you think it will affect performance ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dictionary literal syntax, `{...}`

```
my_list.append({"key1": my_text1, "key2": my_text2})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take it a step further and assume you have a list of texts you want to format as dicts and append to a list:

```
[{"key%d" % (i + 1) : text for i, text in enumerate(text_list)} for text_list in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this other syntax you can try:

```
my_list.append(dict(key1=my_text1, key2=my_text2))
```

Not sure about this issue of "fastest" considering the fact that doing something like this is quite simple in python. The above syntax is probably fastest to *write*, but I have a feeling that's not what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to be declarative:

```
my_list = [{'Key1': 'text1', 'Key2': 'text2'}]
```